# Are there non-projective, but algebraic, hyperkahler varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hyperkaehler

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. I am not sure what the right definition of a hyperkahler variety over $k$ is, but I think the following might be close enough.

**Definition.** 
A smooth proper connected scheme $X$ over $k$ is a *hyperkahler variety (over $k$)* if $\mathrm{h}^{2,0}(X) = 1$, the etale fundamental group $\pi_1^{et}(X)$ of $X$ is trivial,   $\omega_X$ is trivial, and **(added later)** the generator of $\mathrm{H}^{2,0}(X)$ is everywhere non-degenerate.

With this definition, it is not clear whether every hyperkahler variety over $k$ is projective. If $X$ is a two-dimensional hyperkahler variety over $k$, then $X$ is projective. But what about $\dim X > 2$?

> > Is every hyperkahler variety over $k$ projective?

PS. Please feel free to correct my definition of a hyperkahler variety over $k$.

Comment: That is not the correct definition: a product of a hyperkaehler variety and a Calabi-Yau threefold will satisfy that condition by Kuenneth.  You should add the hypothesis that the generator of $H^{2,0}(X)=H^0(X,\bigwedge^2 \Omega_{X/k})$ is everywhere nondegenerate.

Comment: Maybe the toric hyperkähler varieties (a.k.a. hypertoric varieties) of Hausel-Sturmfels ([2002](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2015052), Def. 6.1)?

Comment: FZ: It seems that the OP is interested in compact hyperkahler manifolds

Comment: (Hyper)Kaehler or (hyper)Kähler and étale are right!

Answer (score 2):

With the correct definition of hyperkähler (which as Jason said requires $H^0(X,\Omega^2_X)$ to be generated by a holomorphic symplectic form), there are examples constructed by Yoshioka in section 4.4 [here.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002080100255) The field $k=\mathbb{C}$.

These are non-Kähler compact complex simply connected holomorphic symplectic manifolds which are bimeromorphic to a projective hyperkähler manifold via a Mukai flop. They are therefore Moishezon, but certainly not projective. They are also discussed for example in the book by [Gross-Huybrechts-Joyce,](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9783540440598) example 21.7.

Comment: This does not anser the question, which asks for hyperkähler *schemes*.

Comment: I see, I was just looking at the title which asked for "algebraic" and I thought the OP wanted an algebraic space. Well, I don't know the answer to the actual question then.